# tmux new session doesn't work with php shell_exec

Tags: php, tmux

I'm actually making a script to reboot my game server.
I do this and it work:

```
shell_exec('killall -s 9 srcds_linux srcds_run');
shell_exec('/home/gmodserver/gmodserver start');
```

But normally the start script create a tmux session called

```
gmodserver
```

With terminal, it create it correctly, but not with my php page (my server start but it doesn't create the tmux session)

So I tried this:

```
shell_exec('tmux new-session -d -s test');
```

And it doesn't create a session too

(I don't see the test session if I make `tmux ls`)

I hope you can help me

EDIT:

I made some test and know I know my tmux session nicely start but I don't know on which user

EDIT AGAIN:

When I make a `ps aux | grep tmux` I see my tmux session on my good user. But when I go on the nice user and I make `tmux ls` on this good user, I don't see my session. Its really strange

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure tmux is in your PATH for this function? What if you use the full path to the tmux binary (eg /usr/bin/tmux)?

Comment: It work, because with a test the first try it work and second refresh it write:
`duplicate session: *mysession name*`, but the session isn't created on my apache running user. Now i'm looking for how to find on wich user the session is created